# jqgrid subgrid becomes main grid when clicking on plus icon

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm having problems implementing a jqgrid as subgrid.  When I click on the plus icon, the subgrid becomes the main and the main dissapears. The data part seems ok as the children are matching every row in main grid. Child grid seems to occupy main grid div and loses it's own div.
Here's the code:

```
            <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="JqGridTest1.aspx.cs" Inherits="JQGridDemo.JqGridTest1" %>
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head id="Head1" runat="server">
            <title></title>
            <link href="JQGridReq/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="JQGridReq/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script src="JQGridReq/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="JQGridReq/jquery.json-2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="JQGridReq/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="JQGridReq/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="JQGridReq/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $.extend($.jgrid.defaults,
            { datatype: 'json' },
            { ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data, textStatus) {
                    if (textStatus == "success") {
                        var thegrid = $("#grdParam")[0];
                        thegrid.addJSONData(data.d);
                        thegrid.grid.hDiv.loading = false;
                        switch (thegrid.p.loadui) {
                            case "disable":
                                break;
                            case "enable":
                                $("#load_" + thegrid.p.id).hide();
                                break;
                            case "block":
                                $("#lui_" + thegrid.p.id).hide();
                                $("#load_" + thegrid.p.id).hide();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            });
                    jQuery("#grdParam").jqGrid({
                        url: 'JqGridTest1.aspx/GetDataTableGroup',
                        datatype: 'json',
                        mtype: 'POST',
                        height: 250,
                        colNames: ['GroupID', 'SubGroup', 'ParameterName', 'Value', 'Value2', 'UserInsert', 'InsertDate', 'UserUpdate', 'UpdateDate', 'Active'],
                        colModel: [{
                            name: 'GroupID',
                            index: 'GroupID',
                            width: 40,
                            editable: true,
                            editoptions: {
                                readonly: true,
                                size: 10
                            },
                            editrules: { edithidden: true }
                        },
            {
                name: 'SubGroup',
                index: 'SubGroup',
                width: 40,
                editable: true,
                editoptions: {
                    readonly: true,
                    size: 10
                },
                align: "left",
                size: 100,
                editrules: { edithidden: true }
            },
            {
                name: 'ParameterName',
                index: 'ParameterName',
                width: 100,
                align: "left",
                editable: true,
                size: 100
            },
            {
                name: 'Value',
                index: 'Value',
                width: 100,
                align: "left",
                editable: true,
                size: 100
            },
            {
                name: 'Value2',
                index: 'Value2',
                width: 100,
                align: "left",
                editable: true,
                size: 100
            },
            {
                name: 'UserInsert',
                index: 'UserInsert',
                width: 100,
                align: "left",
                editable: false,
                size: 100
            },
            {
                name: 'InsertDate',
                index: 'InsertDate',
                width: 100,
                align: "left",
                editable: false,
                size: 100,
                sorttype: 'date',
                datefmt: 'Y-m-d'
            },
            {
                name: 'UserUpdate',
                index: 'UserUpdate',
                width: 100,
                align: "left",
                editable: false,
                size: 100
            },
            {
                name: 'UpdateDate',
                index: 'UpdateDate',
                width: 100,
                align: "left",
                editable: false,
                size: 100,
                sorttype: 'date',
                datefmt: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            },
            {
                name: 'Active',
                index: 'Active',
                width: 100,
                align: "left",
                edittype: "checkbox",
                editable: true,
                size: 100
            }
            ],
                        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                        rowNum: 10,
                        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                        sortname: 'GroupID',
                        sortorder: 'asc',
                        subGrid: true,
                        subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
                            var subgrid_table_id;
                            subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t";
                            jQuery("#" + subgrid_id).html("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'></table>");
                            jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                                url: 'JqGridTest1.aspx/GetDataTableSubGroup',
                                data: "{'pPageSize':'" + $("#" + subgrid_table_id).getGridParam("rowNum") +
            "','pCurrentPage':'" + $("#" + subgrid_table_id).getGridParam("page") +
            "','pSortColumn':'" + $("#" + subgrid_table_id).getGridParam("sortname") +
            "','pSortOrder':'" + $("#" + subgrid_table_id).getGridParam("sortorder") + "'}", //PageMethod Parametros de entrada
                                postData: {
                                    GroupID: row_id
                                }
            ,
                                datatype: 'json',
                                mtype: 'POST',
                                height: 150,
                                colNames: ['Grupo', 'Sub Grupo', 'Nombre', 'Valor 1', 'Valor 2', 'Usuario Insercion', 'Fecha Insercion', 'Usuario Actualizacion', 'Fecha Actualizacion', 'Active'],
                                colModel: [{
                                    name: 'GroupID',
                                    index: 'GroupID',
                                    width: 40,
                                    editable: true,
                                    editoptions: {
                                        readonly: true,
                                        size: 10
                                    },
                                    editrules: { edithidden: true }
                                },
            {
                name: 'SubGroup',
                index: 'SubGroup',
                width: 40,
                editable: true,
                editoptions: {
                    readonly: true,
                    size: 10
                },
                align: "left",
                size: 100,
                editrules: { edithidden: true }
            },
            {
                name: 'ParameterName',
                index: 'ParameterName',
                width: 100,
                align: "left",
                editable: true,
                size: 100
            },
            {
                name: 'Value',
                index: 'Value',
                width: 100,
                align: "left",
                editable: true,
                size: 100
            },
            {
                name: 'Value2',
                index: 'Value2',
                width: 100,
                align: "left",
                editable: true,
                size: 100
            },
            {
                name: 'UserInsert',
                index: 'UserInsert',
                width: 100,
                align: "left",
                editable: false,
                size: 100
            },
            {
                name: 'InsertDate',
                index: 'InsertDate',
                width: 100,
                align: "left",
                editable: false,
                size: 100,
                sorttype: 'date',
                datefmt: 'Y-m-d'
            },
            {
                name: 'UserUpdate',
                index: 'UserUpdate',
                width: 100,
                align: "left",
                editable: false,
                size: 100
            },
            {
                name: 'UpdateDate',
                index: 'UpdateDate',
                width: 100,
                align: "left",
                editable: false,
                size: 100,
                sorttype: 'date',
                datefmt: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            },
            {
                name: 'Active',
                index: 'Active',
                width: 100,
                align: "left",
                edittype: "checkbox",
                editable: true,
                size: 100
            }
            ],
                                pager: jQuery('#pager2'),
                                sortname: 'GroupID',
                                sortorder: 'asc',
                                multiboxonly: false,
                                viewrecords: true,
                                imgpath: 'Themes/images',
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                serializeGridData: function (data) {
                                    return $.toJSON(data);
                                }
                            })
                        },
                        multiboxonly: false,
                        viewrecords: true,
                        imgpath: 'Themes/images',
                        serializeGridData: function (data) {
                            return $.toJSON(data);
                        }
                    }).navGrid("#pager", { edit: true, add: true, search: true, del: true },
            { url: "JqGridTest1.aspx/EditData", closeAfterEdit: true },
            { url: "JqGridTest1.aspx/EditData", closeAfterAdd: true, beforeShowForm: function (formid) {
                //jQuery("#ParameterName").focus();
                //$("#ParameterName").focus();
                jQuery("#GroupID").val("AUTOMATIC VALUE");
                jQuery("#SubGroup").val("0");
            }, afterShowForm: function (formid) {
                $("#ParameterName").focus();
            }
            },
            { url: "JqGridTest1.aspx/DeleteData" });
                });
                jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
                    ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
                    recreateForm: true,
                    serializeEditData: function (postData) {
                        return JSON.stringify(postData);
                    }
                });

            </script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <table id="grdParam" class="scroll" align="center" width="100%">
            </table>
            <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align: center;">
            </div>
            </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should try to reduce the scope of your question - is it a CSS problem? A C# problem? There is just too much code to look at and it's probably not reproducible locally by other users. Also, consider posting a JSFiddle if possible. It might help you get more and better help. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that I was using the same extend function for both main grid and subgrid.

The following code was removed and json connection was added to main grid and subgrid connection functions and worked ok:

```
            $.extend($.jgrid.defaults,
                    { datatype: 'json' },
                { ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (data, textStatus) {
                        if (textStatus == "success") {
                            var thegrid = $("#grdParam")[0];
                            thegrid.addJSONData(data.d);
                            thegrid.grid.hDiv.loading = false;
                            switch (thegrid.p.loadui) {
                                case "disable":
                                    break;
                                case "enable":
                                    $("#load_" + thegrid.p.id).hide();
                                    break;
                                case "block":
                                    $("#lui_" + thegrid.p.id).hide();
                                    $("#load_" + thegrid.p.id).hide();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                });
```